# Storing JS strings containing binary data in WebSQL

Tags: javascript, string, binaryfiles, web-sql

I need to store JavaScript strings that contain binary data using WebSQL. I know that user technologies could be used (IndexedDB, LocalStorage, ...), but for some reasons I need to stick to WebSQL. As the quota is limited and the data could get big, I don't want to Base64-encode the data.

Consider the following JS Code (and a corresponding [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yu7g/)):

```
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
function test(str){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE test (val)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(val) VALUES (?)',[str]);
        tx.executeSql('SELECT val FROM test',[],function(tx,result){
            var str2 = result.rows.item(0).val;
            console.log(str + " (" + str.length + ") - " + str2 + " (" + str2.length + ")");
        });
    });
}
test("Foo");
test("A\0B");
```

which outputs

> Foo (3) - Foo (3)
>
> AB (3) - A (1)

in Chrome and Safari.

As you can see the zero-byte and all charachters after it get eaten by WebSQL. Do you know if there is any way to put this string into WebSQL without enlarging it (e.g. by Base64 encoding), and without using another storage technology?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually it **does** work. The problem was not storing the binary string, but retrieving it. When the result contained a zero byte, the String was considered to be completed.

WebSQL provides as function `hex` which returns the hex representation of a String. When storing for example `"A\0B"`, the function will return *410042*.  Using this I got my example to work (see [updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3Yu7g/1/)):

```
//convert hex representation back to string
function hex2str(hex){
    var result = new Array(hex.length / 2);
    for(var i = 0, j = 0; j < hex.length; i++, j+=2)
        result[i] = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(hex.substr(j,2),16));
    return result.join("");

}
var db = openDatabase('mydb', '1.0', 'Test DB', 2 * 1024 * 1024);
function test(str){
    db.transaction(function (tx) {  
        tx.executeSql('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS test');
        tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE test (val)');
        tx.executeSql('INSERT INTO test(val) VALUES (?)',[str]);
        //magic occurs here
        tx.executeSql('SELECT hex(val) as val FROM test',[],function(tx,result){
            var str2 = hex2str(result.rows.item(0).val);
            console.log(str + " (" + str.length + ") - " + str2 + " (" + str2.length + ")");
        });
    });
}
test("Foo");  //Foo (3) - Foo (3)
test("A\0B"); //AB  (3) - AB  (3)
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way to save binary data in websql is base64 encoding.
If your data is really going to be very big and prone to crossing 5/10MB limits of browser quotas, base64 conversion is not going to be the main culprit ( it just bloats the data by an average factor of 4/3 ). 
If your original data is already about to cross the quotas, you better think of possible workarounds.

Comment: see my own answer, I got it to work without the need to reencode it